# Auto hyperlink in multiple line/multiple links cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-apps

Big file (+1k rows) imported from a CSV file.
file has a column with file addresses like:

`http://www.whatever.whatever/file1.jpg`

some rows have more than one file address in said column, separated by "line breaks", so some rows are

```
http://www.whatever.whatever/file2.jpg
http://www.whatever.whatever/file3.jpg
http://www.whatever.whatever/file4.jpg
```

and so on...

The rows with 1 address are auto-transformed into a hyperlink by google sheets, which is exactly what I want.
The rows with more than one file address are left as is, which is the problem.
How can I auto-link the rows with more than one file address without having to go 1 by 1?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can do hyperlinks with richtext.

Comment: Can you explain further? thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can refer to this sample code:

```
function addHyperlink(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var links = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();

  links.forEach((cellLink,index) => {
    Logger.log(cellLink);
    Logger.log(cellLink.includes('\n'));
    
    //Check if cell value has multiple links (contains line break)
    if(cellLink.includes('\n')){
      var tmpUrl = cellLink.split('\n');
      var rText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(cellLink);
      var startOffset = 0;
      tmpUrl.forEach(url=>{
        Logger.log(url);
        Logger.log(url.length);
        Logger.log(startOffset);
        rText.setLinkUrl(startOffset,(startOffset+url.length),url);
        startOffset = startOffset + url.length + 1;
      });
      var value = rText.build();
      sheet.getRange(index + 1,1).setRichTextValue(value);
    }
  });

}
```

### What it does?

1. Get all the cell values in Column A. Change 2-d array into 1-d array values using `array.flat()`
2. Check each values if it contains a line break using `array.includes()`
3. If multiple url found, split each url into a temporary array variable.
4. Create a [RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder) using [SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newrichtextvalue). Set the text based on the original cell's value using [setText(text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#settexttext)
5. Loop each individual url to get its url length to be used to set the hyperlink's `start offset` and `end offset` using [setLinkUrl(startOffset, endOffset, linkUrl)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setlinkurlstartoffset,-endoffset,-linkurl). Adjust the `start offset` every time a url was processed.
6. Use [build()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#build) to generate a [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value). Set the cell range rich text value using [setRichTextValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue)

### Output:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues regarding the solution provided

Comment: Anyway I could give the hyperlink a sequencial name like "Link 1", "Link 2"...?
Some cells have more than 20 files and, as you can see from your  screenshot, it's hard to keep track of the ones you have opened and the ones you didn't cause you can only read the beginning of the address. Thanks